# How can text area contents can be replaced to "*" by skipping the new line character

Tags: java, swing, textarea

I have a requirement where I need to replace all the text into "*" (basically masking) at run time entering into jtextArea. Mean to say I am storing the key into a variable at textArea displaying that as "*".
Got a code for that which is as :

```
public class App {
            String text= "";
            App(){
                JFrame f= new JFrame();
               // final JTextArea area=new JTextArea();
                JTextArea jTextArea=new JTextArea();

                jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                   if(Character.isLetter(e.getKeyChar())) {
                  System.out.println(text);
                     //text = text + e.getKeyChar();
                       text += String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
                       System.out.println(text);
                       jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll("[a-z]", "*"));
                   }
                   //System.out.println(text);
               }

            });
                System.out.println(text);
            jTextArea.setBounds(10,30, 200,200);
            jTextArea.setAutoscrolls(true);
            f.add(jTextArea);
            f.setSize(300,300);
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new App();
        }

}
```

Here the problem is its converting my "New line" too and adding that to first line itself.

What my requirement is :

Input :

```
Hello

how
are

you
```

**Should appear as :**

```
*****

***
***

***
```

Kindly advise

Comment: Looks like expectation is not appearing properly but ultimately  every character has to replaced by "*" and new line will come as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are not appending new line characters to the `text` variables, which means that `text` will always have letters, but never new lines. Since you set the text field's text to be `text`, `text` should have those new line characters too.

You should just remove the if statement, as the check is already being "done" by the regex `[a-z]` in the `replaceAll` call.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    text += String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
    jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll("[a-z]", "*"));
}
```

However, this still doesn't handle stuff like backspace and pasting, not to mention that it would be better if `text` were a `StringBuilder`. But I'll leave it to you to improve your code.

Comment: thanks! True it don't need any if validation. I was doing wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code if this is what you are looking for

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class App {
            String text= "";
            App(){
                JFrame f= new JFrame();
               // final JTextArea area=new JTextArea();
                JTextArea jTextArea=new JTextArea();

                jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                       text += String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
                       System.out.println(text);
                       jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll("[a-z]", "*"));
               }

            });
                System.out.println(text);
            jTextArea.setBounds(10,30, 200,200);
            jTextArea.setAutoscrolls(true);
            f.add(jTextArea);
            f.setSize(300,300);
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new App();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other two answers both have the problem of only replacing alphabetical input, therefore ignoring all numbers, special characters or whitespaces, I thought I'd add on as well. If you actually just want to replace ANY character to a star, you don't even have to play around with RegEx and replacing characters, you might as well just append a star every time `keyReleased` event is called.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class App
{
    String displayText = "";
    String valueText = "";

    App()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        // final JTextArea area=new JTextArea();
        JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();

        jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {

            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    displayText += "*";
                    valueText += String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
                    jTextArea.setText(displayText);
                }
            }

        });
        System.out.println(valueText);
        jTextArea.setBounds(10, 30, 200, 200);
        jTextArea.setAutoscrolls(true);
        f.add(jTextArea);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new App();
    }

}
```

If you want to keep the typed in value in the backend, just save the typed in value somewhere and only display `text`.

Comment: It won't consider the "enter" and text will keep appending to new line. Looks like will loose the input entered but the need is like input has to masked as well as value has to remain as it is so that can use the same at other place.

Comment: 1.) My bad, didn't consider the enter case. 2.) I did tell you how to keep the value, by saving it in a different variable that doesn't get displayed to the user. It's thanksgiving though, so I edited my code to include those two conditions.

Comment: No luck! Its still appending the text into first line itself and ignoring the new line. This will work to over come the issue : 
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    text += String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
                    jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll(".", "*"));
                 }

But one challage which I am seeing is its considering "backspace" too which is not right. I am thinking what regex will help to fix this

Answer (score 0):

This is complete code which worked as per expectation :

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

    public class App {
            //String text= "";
        String text = "";
            App(){
                JFrame f= new JFrame();
               // final JTextArea area=new JTextArea();
                JTextArea jTextArea=new JTextArea();

                jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    char ch = e.getKeyChar();
                    if (e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
                        //System.out.println("It Works Backspace pressed..!");
                    }
                    else {
                    text += String.valueOf(ch);
                    }
                    //System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
                    jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll(".", "*"));
                    //jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll(".[\b]", "*"));
                    //jTextArea.setText(text.toString().replaceAll("[\\b].", "*"));
                }

            });
                System.out.println(text);
            jTextArea.setBounds(10,30, 200,200);
            jTextArea.setAutoscrolls(true);
            f.add(jTextArea);
            f.setSize(300,300);
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new App();
        }

}
```